# Count() of a column in leftjoin (that have custom where)

Tags: laravel, join, laravel-4, eloquent

Anyone can help me please, I didn't find how to solve that.

I want to show subjects list, and a column total responses (only response that have statut=approved).

my tables looks like :

```
subjects(idsubject, title)
responses(idresponse, idsubject, message, status)
```

so I did:

```
$subjects= Subject::select('subjects.*', "count(responses.id) as responses" )
->leftJoin('responses', function($join)
{
    $join->on('responses.idsubject', '=', 'subjects.idsubject')
    ->where('responses.status', '=', '1');
})
->get();
```

But I get error message

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'count(responses.id)'

How I can solve that please?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use for this `selectRaw` instead of `select` - for `select` you can use only column names:

```
$subjects= Subject::selectRaw("subjects.*, count(responses.id) as responses")
->leftJoin('responses', function($join)
{
    $join->on('responses.idsubject', '=', 'subjects.idsubject')
    ->where('responses.status', '=', '1');
})
->get();
```